# TreeView List Android

Tags: android, treeview

I want a Tree View list in my project .SO i referred to this link (https://github.com/Polidea/tree-view-list-android).
But i am not getting how to get the library of this Project.
I have tried (https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1534)link also.In the last link,I am getting tree View List for Standard Adapter but in My project i want an custom Adapter.

Can anyone please suggest me??

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this android treeView Library, I used it before and I think it's a good library for creating tree view in android. it's give more flexible options to create your own custom Adapter and listView

this is github link of the library

https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView

you also can see the demo of this library on google play

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.unnamed.b.atv.demo

Comment: ,I have used this library but i am not getting how to implement custom View .So can you please suggest me

Comment: you must create your own layout and java class that extends `TreeNode.BaseNodeViewHolder` class and override `createNodeView` method. in the github page there is step by step tutorial!